# Best way to access adjacent components / fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am looking for a way to access components / field that are either in the same items array as the accessing one or even only in a same parent items array (the last one is just a option).

In ExtJS3 this was easy by simply defining a `ref` in the owner container but I didn't found anything like that in ExtJS4.

I know that I can use `Ext.ComponentQuery()` or the shortcuts `up()` / `down()` or even `Ext.getCmp()` but they are all not what I am looking for, cause they just executes a bunch of code while the `ref` was such an easy Way to do things. 
Yes, I am aware of the fact that using a ComponentQuery is much more fail safe than the use of hard coded references. But I just want to know if there are some other ways to do this.

Comment: I use refs all the time in my controllers: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs

Comment: Well I don't mentioned Controller cause I don't use them. I know that they know have a ref system, but that is not what I am talking about... So that did not help at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some tricks I have used:

```
//lookup by name
formPanel.getForm().findField('state'); 

//lookup using nextSibling/prevSibling in a fieldset or fieldcontainer
myField.ownerCt.nextSibling('textfield[fieldLabel=Description]')
```

Here `fieldLabel` property is used to narrow down field selection but you can use ANY property at all. So if you construct a field with a property `ref` you can then use it to select your field similar how you would use it in a `ComponentQuery` .

Comment: thanks for accepting! I'll +1 geronimos answer as well for being first.

Comment: Thanks! You guys seen jsfiddle issues? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153630/why-are-answers-with-jsfiddle-net-in-body-not-allowed

Comment: I have found another way to access adjacent components which is exactly what I was looking for. Therefore I removed the 'correct answer' from you. Fell free to comment why my new approach my be wrong . It it comes out that both approaches nearly the same I recheck your answer. But for now the new one looks leaner to me.

Answer (score 11):

Alternately, for your case of getting the next element in a container, you can use the `nextSibling` or `prevSibling`. All components have these methods. It would be a little less walking around the DOM structure. They also allow for a selector argument.

They are described in the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-nextSibling).

Comment: +1 and thanks for the reply and yes this seems to be fitting for my needs. And even if @dbrin answers contains nearly the same I will mark his answer as correct (he explained it along with an example) cause I can't tell which one of you answered first.