# EXT.JS getting a list of items from a fieldset

Tags: extjs

How can I get a list of items from a `Ext.form.Fieldset`? I'm trying to find a component based on one of its properties, this is what I've got so far:

```
Ext.each(container.items, function (component) {

    if (component.name == config.name) {
        component.doUpdate(config);
    }

}, me);
```

Of course, items is undefined...so what can I do to access the components contained in my container, which is a fieldset?

Comment: was the answer below useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use container.down(selector) or if its a form field use form.findField(name).

See this answer on the different ways to 'find' things in an extjs app: 
[Testing extjs apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727481/testing-extjs-apps/13730075#13730075)

For form fields here is an answer that lists different tricks: [Best way to access adjacent components / fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190870/best-way-to-access-adjacent-components-fields/13202813#13202813)

**EDIT**: Use [container.query(selector](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-query)) method to get an array of objects. As down() method returns first found.

Comment: I'm looking to get a collection of components, not form fields. Will container.down('myapp.mycomponent') return a list of components?

Comment: see edits and make sure to click on the link to see the documentation