# Ext JS 4: Getters and setters in view

Tags: oop, extjs, extjs4, getter-setter

I've been thinking about this problem for a while, and I can't seem to come up with a reasonable solution. What I would like to do is create getters/setters for a textfield/its value in my view. I realize that the preferred Ext JS way is using a reference within the controller and getting it that way, but that doesn't feel very object-oriented to me. I'd also have to wrap these getters and setters because I want to output a message if the getter returns undefined. What I'd like to do is create my own getters/setters or somehow override the default getters/setters. Here are some ways I was thinking of accomplishing this.

I was thinking I could use the `config {}`, but that appears to only work for variables I want to define. I then was thinking of using an id somehow, but the community seems split on whether that's a good practice or not. Which leads to my current solution... wrapping. Here's my code:

> **LoginWindow**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.loginWindow',
    autoShow: true,
    closable: false,
    border: 0,
    plain: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    title: "Enter your username",
    modal: true,
    config: {
        buttons: [{
            text: "Ok"
        }],
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            id: 'loginUserInput',
            name: 'loginUserInput',
            msgTarget: 'under',
            validator: function(value) {
                if (Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
                    return "You need to enter a username.";
                }
                return true;
            }
        }]
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(config);
    },

    getButton: function() {
        console.log('here');
    }
});
```

> **MyController**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Chat', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [
        'Views.ChatModule.view.LoginWindow'
    ],

    refs: [{
        ref: 'loginWindow',
        selector: 'loginWindow',
        xtype: 'loginWindow',
        autoCreate: true
    }, {
        ref: 'loginUserInput',
        selector: '#loginUserInput'
    }],

    init: function() {
        // The events controller oversees
        this.control({
            'loginWindow button[text="Ok"]': {
                'click': this.onSubmitLoginWindow
            }
        });
    },

    getLoginUserInputValue: function() {
        var loginUserInput = this.getLoginUserInput();
        if (loginUserInput) {
            var username = loginUserInput.getValue();
            if (username) {
                console.log(username);
            } else {
                console.warn("username is undefined");
            }
        }
        console.warn("loginUserInput is undefined");
    },

    onSubmitLoginWindow: function(button, event, eOpts) {
        this.getLoginUserInputValue();
    }
});
```

This works, and I realize it's a very nit-picky thing, but it just doesn't feel right to have the getter in the controller. I feel like it'd be more object-oriented if it was in the Window. However, if I put it in the Window, I believe my only option is to lean on ids or manually create the textfield in the Window's initComponent--which would involve saving off a reference of the textfield in there, but that seems a bit inefficient... as I would have to make a call to doLayout as well.

Just to reiterate, I'd love to have the getters/setters in the Window, and I'm looking for a quick way to reference it, similar to how the controller references objects. I believe the main answer will be to use ids and making a call to `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginUserInput')` in the Window, but I'd like to know if there were any better approaches out there... like overriding the auto generated getters/setters or adding a simple getter/setter for an input's value.

Cross-post from the [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?272394-Getters-and-setters-inside-view.).

**Edit**

I guess I was a bit unclear with what I want.  As a more general statement, instead of jamming all things related to my view in the controller, I'd like to store it all in the view itself, which includes things like getters/setters.  One of these getters/setters just so happens to be the loginUserInput getter.

Using a model is an interesting idea, but I feel like that would be a whole lot of overhead for singleton values.  I'm basically looking for something like Java's [setters/getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters) in the LoginWindow view... and hopefully something as simple as (or close to) Java's.

The idea of including (encapsulating) it in the view makes the controller a bit cleaner, and if I delete the view, I'm deleting its functions as well, so I don't have to go hunting for the functions in the controller... all I have to worry about is removing the references (which should be minimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thoughts are something like this:

```
...
items: [],
constructor: function(config) {
  this.loginUserInput = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
    fieldLabel: 'Username',
    id: 'loginUserInput',
    name: 'loginUserInput',
    msgTarget: 'under',
    validator: function(value) {
      if (Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
        return "You need to enter a username.";
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
  this.items.push(this.loginUserInput);
  this.callParent(config);
},

getLoginUserInput: function() {
  var loginUserInput = this.loginUserInput;
  if (!loginUserInput) {
    console.warn("LoginWindow::getLoginUserInput: loginUserInput is undefined");
  }
  return loginUserInput;
}
```

So instead of letting Ext do its magic, I am now instantiating the object on my own, which then allows me to store away a reference of it, so I can easily access it in my getter.  I just wonder if this is creating any sort of performance hit.  It doesn't seem like it'd be that much worse... it actually seems like it'd be a bit better because I'm not referencing this object by its ID, and I don't have to go searching for it when I need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "OO" way that you're looking is to work with a `Ext.data.Model` for your form. If you look at the [Ext.form.Basic](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) you have methods to manipulate a model (called record) and also get the object with the values of your view. So you need:

1. When you create your form, use `loadRecord()` to bind your form to a Model.
2. At any time you need, use `getValues()` to retrieve the values of your form fields.
3. When submiting your form, use `getRecord()` and `getValues()` to sync your record.

---

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Login',{
  fields : [{
    name: 'username',
    type: 'string'
  },{
    name: 'password',
    type: 'string'
  }]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Login',{
  ...
  refs : [{
    selector: 'window form',
    ref: 'formPanel'
  }],
  ...
  openForm : function() {
    //load your form and then bind the new record
    var formPanel = this.getFormPanel(), //Ext.form.Panel
        form = formPanel.getForm(); //Ext.form.Basic

    form.loadRecord(Ext.create('MyApp.model.Login'));

  },
  save : function() {
    //get the values in the view
    var form = this.getFormPanel().getForm(),
        vals = form.getValues(),
        record = form.getRecord();

    console.log(vals); //see the object representation of your view here
    record.set(vals); //update your model

    //do whatever you need with your model

  }
  ...
});
```

This is an good example when you need to save the form data. In the login I think you can work directly with `getValues()` without binding it to a `Ext.data.Model`.

Comment: See update... not sure if that's more clear or confusing, so let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite certain what problem you are trying to solve to be honest with you.

If you do not like controllers listening to buttons within your window, you can have button handlers witin your view definition fire custom events that controllers can listen on. Use `fireEvent` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/extjs-4-event-handling-tutorials). And by the way initConfig is a recommended way to setup your views. You can break it up into methods if you wish, 'this' reference is available and is the View component being instantiated.

If you need to find inner components within the View there are many methods available from `up` /`down` to `nextSibling` and `query` .

```
For Components:
    • Ext.getCmp(id)
    • Ext.ComponentQuery.query()
    • up() 
    • down() 
    • nextSibling() 
    • previousSibling()
    • child()
    • previousNode()
plus various find.. Methods
```

**EDIT**

I think I understood what you mean by getter and setters. Ext forms have the fields finders to make it easy to get and set data to individual fields. See these SO questions: [Best way to access adjacent components / fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190870/best-way-to-access-adjacent-components-fields/13202813#13202813) and [EXT.JS getting a list of items from a fieldset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884322/ext-js-getting-a-list-of-items-from-a-fieldset/13884489#13884489)

Also like Sergio said there is getRecord getValues and setRecord methods on the form to deal with data binding. Thats it.

**EDIT2**

The best starting point guide that shows clear and claen MVC patterns as well as form handling. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: Up/down/nextSibling/previousSibling/child/previousNode all seem so constraining... you need to know where you are in relation to the parent.  Doesn't seem like good OOP.

May I ask where your statement "And by the way initConfig is a recommended way to setup your views" comes from?  Does Sencha say to do it this way?  And if so, do you mean to create my actual button in the initConfig of LoginWindow?  Just curious.  Also, I added an update to my initial question.

Comment: See update on your original question. To answer your question on recommended approach: config is only really used in Sencha Touch product. In extjs you rarely needed it at all unless you are creating a class that does not extend an extjs Component. Here is a good way to initialize you components: http://mitchellsimoens.com/?p=59

Comment: Interesting... from that blog, it seems like I should be creating my buttons and items in the initComponent... if I did that, I could set a reference to each component within the actual class, which would make my getters/setters very easy to access.

Comment: I feel like that'd be more expensive though... I think I'd have to call the parent before I could push to the LoginWindow's items array, which would force me to call a doLayout on the LoginWindow, so its items/buttons would show.  I'll experiment with this tomorrow.

Comment: NO that is not what it advises you to do. Containers hold all of its child components in the items array. You can find those items using methods described above. And NO you never call doLayout anymore - those examples you mayhave seen a re old and obsolete.

Comment: If you want some more examples of various types you can look at these: http://jsfiddle.net/user/dbrin/fiddles/